# Alert user if the current page is temporarily left with React + React-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history, html5-history

If a user attempts to change the active page (window/tab/etc) from our page to another while `myState` is `true`, we want to notify/alert the user in React JS using `react-router`.

I tried implementing it with the help [`TransitionHook`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ConfirmingNavigation.md) and React-router's [`Confirming Navigation`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ConfirmingNavigation.md) article. Though these only point out / work when user wants to close the page or reload it. Whereas I need to know when user just **temporarily leaves the page without necessarily closing it**.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If by "leaving the page",  you mean that the page is open, but a different window has popped up, you could consider using the `document.hasFocus` property. Here is one way I handled a problem that was tangentially related:

`componentDidMount: function (){
    setInterval(()=>{
      if (document.hasFocus()){
        this.checkServerState();
      }
    }, 
},`

Comment: Actually that's a pretty neat solution that will probably work for us. Thanks! Nonetheless, I'll just wait a little more to see if there's any react or react-router specific api that handles the thing.